# unir mas de dos tablas en una sola consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join, tablas

buen dia, resulta que tengo 4 tablas entrada que relaciona los datos principales de una factura de compra y su relacion va con detalle_entrada que relaciona los articulos con esa factura por medio de su identrada, las otras dos son venta y su relacion con detalle_venta, igual con su relacion por el idventa;
resulta que quiero unir esta tabla en una tabla llamada movimientos pero no quiero duplicar datos en la base de datos solo quiero lo siguiente:

muestro el ejemplo:

entradas = identrada, proveedor, num_comprobante, fecha_hora

detalle_entrada = iddetalle_entrada, identrada, idarticulo, cantidad

ventas = idventa, cliente, num_comprobante, fecha_hora

detalle_venta = iddetalle_venta, idventa, idarticulo, cantidad

la tabla persona contiene los datos de cliente y proveedor asi:

persona = idpersona, nombre, tipo_persona, documento, telefono

estas son las filas de las tablas y sus relaciones ya las mencione anteriormente.

Deseo elaborar una consulta sql que me una los datos de estas 4 tablas para ver detalle de movimiento de entradas y salidas por referencia de articulo.

```
<?php

$sql1="SELECT i.idingreso,
              i.idproveedor,
              i.idusuario,
              i.num_comprobante as facentrada,
              i.fecha_hora as fentrada,
              di.iddetalle_ingreso,
              di.idingreso,
              di.idarticulo,
              di.cantidad as cant_entrada,
              di.precio_venta,
              p.idpersona,
              p.nombre as nameproveedor
         FROM detalle_ingreso di
         INNER JOIN ingreso i ON i.idingreso=di.idingreso
         INNER JOIN persona p  ON i.idproveedor=p.idpersona
         WHERE di.idarticulo=$idinsumo";

         $rsta = ejecutarconsulta($sql1);
         
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="example1">
                            <thead>
                              <th>idEntrada</th>
                              <th>idSalida</th>
                              <th>Proveedor</th>
                              <th>Cliente</th>                              
                              <th>Fact Entrada</th>
                              <th>Fact Salida</th>
                              <th>Cant Entrada.</th>
                              <th>Cant Salida.</th>
                              <th>Fecha Entrada</th>
                              <th>Fecha Salida</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
                            while ($fila = $rsta->fetch_object()){
                              $identrada = $fila->idingreso;
                            ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center"><?php echo $identrada; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila->idproveedor; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila->factentrada; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila->cant_entrada; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($fila->fentrada)); ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

La tabla muestra campos sin datos es por que no se como ingresar o llamar la tabla ventas pues se me mezcla la informacion.

agradezco puedan ayudarme con esto...gracias..!

Comment: Tu consulta: ¿funciona directo en mysql?

Comment: si claro si funciona pero solo hasta donde lo deje en la mita solo la tabla entradas con detalle entradas me falta unir a ventas y detalle venta y mostrar resultados

Comment: Podrías explicar qué intentas lograr? No tiene mucho sentido unir compras con ventas...

Comment: Si solo quieres una consulta de las tablas puedes crear una VISTA con las relaciones a las tablas que indicas, luego haces un select a la vista y basta, las vistas son muy recomendables para temas de optimización en base de datos.